# Want to close Popup in Jquery Mobile with Esc Key

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to close popup window with Esc key. Is it possible to close with Esc key when I have set data-dismissible="false". The Popup should not close when clicked outside of the Popup (that's why I have set data-dismissible="false" and it works great). Only problem is I am not able to close with Esc key. Here is my code:

```
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {   
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
       namePopup.close();
    }
});
```

Comment: data-dismissible="false" in docs: "Sets whether clicking outside the popup or pressing Escape while the popup is open will close the popup." -> jQuery Mobile probably overwrites your close call... maybe adding e.stopPropagation(); can help

Comment: To close a popup: $( ".selector" ).popup( "close" ); see api docs here: http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/#method-close

Comment: @Fredrik Voordeckers, thanks for replying. I tried but e.stopPropagation() didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, popupBaisc is the id of the popup.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27) {
            $("#popupBasic").popup("close");
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup">Open Popup</a>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic" data-dismissible="false">
  <p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. For some reason it didn't work for me.